# Drop elements into textbox html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui

I need to add more elements into a textbox using jquery after that to insert into a database..So this script adds one element in textbox when I want to add one that was delete...How to add more then one elements in textbox??help
jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$(".draggable").draggable({
    revert: true,
    helper: 'clone',
    start: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).fadeTo(0, 1);
    }
});

$("#tag").droppable({
    hoverClass: 'active',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        this.value = $(ui.draggable).text();
    }
 });
 });
```

PHP/HTML code

```
  <p><b>Tags:</b></p>       
        <input type="text" name="tag" id="tag" style="width:605px">
                <?php if($tags): ?>
                    <?php foreach($tags as $t): ?>
                        <div class="draggable" style="border:1px solid green;width:100px;height:30px;display:inline-block;background-color:#e6eaff;cursor:default;font-size:18px;">
                            <a href="#" class="tg1" id="<?php echo $t['id']?>" ><?php echo $t['name'] ?></a>
                        </div> 
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>                  
        <br />
```

I want to add more then one element in textbox

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Just "read" the current text inside the textbox into a variable,

```
$("#mytextarea").val()
```

then "combine" it with the new content into another variable and then drop the content of this new variable into the Text-Field.